# ASP.NET - CustomValidator not working after postback

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a simple case.

A custom validator in page Default.aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UplTab1" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>   
        <span>
            <asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CustomValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="MyValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Mon message" ControlToValidate="MyTextBox" OnServerValidate="MyValidator_OnServerValidate" ValidationGroup="MyGroup1"></asp:CustomValidator>
        </span>     
        <span>
            <asp:Button ID="BtnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="MyGroup1" OnClick="BtnSave_OnClick"></asp:Button>
        </span>                     
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void MyValidator_OnServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = MyValidationFunction();
}
```

When I try to validate my textbox control, no problem it works, my function "MyValidator_OnServerValidate" is fired. Then I try to re-submit my form again with same button with a different value in my textbox, but this time my custom validator doesn't work anymore.

My question is why this behavior?

I think it's the postback behavior because if I refresh my page, the custom validator works.

Comment: Does it postback at all? Show more of the code, relevant are on aspx the `TextBox`, **all** validators of it, any clientcode which gets executed, codebehind incl. `Page_Load` and the method `MyValidator_OnServerValidate`. Also try `Display="Static"`.

Comment: It postback the first time with all validator working. The second time it can postback BUT no validator working... I add some code, but it"s very basic sample, no more, no less... It's why I think this so weird ! :(

Comment: Are you using a validation summary to display the message? As it is a server side validator try putting the validation summary inside the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same symptoms. CustomValidator and UpdatePanel acts funny when you have javaScript errors. It may be some innocent javaScript error but it will stop Ajax request to complete. To test that check whether your ajax postback end request is fired correctly.

```
$(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);                        
});

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    alert('Postback!');
}
```